# Call function not working for all sub-classes

Tags: php, oop, call

I'm trying to use the `__call` function to execute instructions before a specific action.

But when I use this code I only get `__call` working once, while I need it to be executed for every  `run()` call.

If I use `$second_child->run()` inside the `run()` of the first child only the `__call`, for the first child, is executing. Any idea why?

```
class ParentClass{
    protected function run(){}
    public function __call($method,$arguments) {
        echo "<br/>######Call ". get_called_class()."########<br>";
        if(method_exists($this, $method)) {
            call_user_func_array(array($this,$method),$arguments);
        }
    }
}
class first_child extends ParentClass{
    protected function run(){
        echo "<br>running " . get_called_class();
        $x= new second_child;
        $x->run();
    }
}
class second_child extends ParentClass{
        protected function run(){
            echo "<br>running " . get_called_class();
        }
}
$y= new first_child;
$y->run();
```

Comment: My output of your script is: ######Call first_child########

running first_child
running second_child, both `run()`'s are getting executed

Comment: @Ray: But both `__call`s are not.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `second_child` extends from `ParentClass`, which introduces the `run` method.

Because of that, `first_child` can actually call the (overridden) protected method in `second_child`, thus bypassing the magic method, which is only called when there is no possibility to directly call a method.

In this case, there is a possibility to call the method, because first_child has access to the protected methods introduced in `ParentClass`, and through polymorphism, PHP actually calls the overridden method in `second_child`.

Comment: `second_child extends ParentClass`

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yeah, that's right. But `run` is already declared in `ParentClass`. So the same answer applies. I will correct it, though.

Comment: The output is `######Call first_child######## running first_child running second_child`.  The `__call` function *is* called, but only for `first_child`, not `second_child`, why?

Comment: Because `first_child->run` is called from outside the class. In that (global?) context, the protected `run` method is inaccessable, so the magic method `__call` is invoked instead. `__call` calls the `run` method of `first_child`, which in turn has direct access to the `run` method of `second_child`.